# I need to create a table but i am getting error of invalid option or missing

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE deposit-1035(
Actno Varchar2(25),
Cname Varchar(25),
Bname Varchar2(25),
Amount Number(8,2),
Adate date);
```

ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
This is error i am getting why?

Comment: Please share more details. That error message looks unrelated to MySQL - are you maybe using Oracle?

Comment: @NicoHaase Oracle bough over MySQL a while back.  The MySQL error codes look like this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Are you sure about that? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c85eca8e2d20e69a17f2e71472ecebfa

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen are you sure about that? Cannot find any reference to an "ORA" prefixed error message in MySQL. Also, "Oracle" is still a database system on its own, not solely the company behind it

Comment: Now I'm not sure.  What database is this, because it looks like Oracle now to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use minus sign in object name deposit-1035

try use an underscore

```
CREATE TABLE deposit_1035
```

or if you really need  minus  for mysql use backtics arount the object name `

```
`deposit-1035`
```

or for oracle use double quote

```
d  "deposit-1035"
```

Answer (score 0):

There're two problems here:

1. `-` is the subtraction operator. If you want to use it in an identifier you need to quote it:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE "deposit-1035" (
       Actno Varchar2(25),
       Cname Varchar(25),
       Bname Varchar2(25),
       Amount Number(8,2),
       Adate date
   );
   ```
2. You are not using MySQL but Oracle database. The syntax and features are completely different, and so is the documentation.